# Secure contents of an SD Card in Android

Tags: android, security, hardware, sd-card, drm

I have some sensitive content data that I provide with my Android application and this data (almost say 1 gb of it) is stored on an SD Card. I want to prevent users from using this card in other places other than the tab itself and reading/copying content off it on a computer or another tablet. I've thought about encryption mechanisms but for the amount of data I have these are very slow and not an option. Are there any hardware settings I could change or file data formats I could use to achieve this? Basically when I remove the card and put into another device I should not be able to copy data from it unless say I have a Pin number or some security mechanism. Most of the content is either pdf files or mp4 videos and I need a sort of software/hardware DRM mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done anything of this sort, but [THIS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/drm/package-summary.html) might be your best bet.

If you can't implement an online service for your content, you could try creating a proxy local service which will handle the DRM Info Requests for you.